# Swift - Get if battery is charging even at 100%

Tags: ios, swift, uidevice

I am making an app in swift, and I need to know if the battery is charging. I know I can use `UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState`, But when it is at 100%, it returns `.Full` instead of `.Charging`. It also returns `.Full` when unplugged on 100%. So is there a way to determine if the battery is charging while at 100%?

Comment: *"is there a way to determine if the battery is charging while at 100%?"* What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said,

> It also returns .Full when unplugged on 100%.

But [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDeviceBatteryState) say (emphasis mine):

> `UIDeviceBatteryStateFull`
>
> The device is plugged into power *and* the battery is 100% charged.

So it seems like the state should change to `.Unplugged` once you remove power. If you *are* seeing `.Full` when the battery is both unplugged and fully charged then that’s a bug (or at least an error in the documentation) and you should report it.

Comment: Well so it is... I thought I looked at the docs well enough but I guess I didn't. Sorry for the really stupid question. Thank you! I'll accept your answer in six minutes when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

You might use this?

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState == .Unplugged {
    //Not charging
} else {
    //Charging
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState has 4 possible return values:

typedef enum {
   UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown,
   UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged,
   UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging,
   **UIDeviceBatteryStateFull**,
} UIDeviceBatteryState;

**UIDeviceBatteryStateFull** indicates the devices is plugged in and fully charged.

Apple Docs are sometimes difficult to navigate at first, but hey are your friend:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDeviceBatteryState